# Load an Angular component only once

Tags: angular

I have two Angular components (let's call them HomeComponent and AboutComponent). When I start the application, HomeComponent is the first that is loaded, it makes a call to a webService, and then presents the results.

If I switch to the AboutComponent (I have a `navbar` with routing) and then I switch back to HomeComponent the component is reloaded (it re-makes the call to the web service).

Is there a way to load this component only once (the first time it's created)?

Comment: You need to inject a service defined as a singleton. Cache the observable there and use `shareReplay`. Then you will only ever have 1 call to the api.

Comment: Beat me to it @Igor Assuming of course this is the underlying issue that OP wants solved :)

Comment: This may have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58812513/2358409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result in a few ways.

- One of them implement a cache service, and using interceptor cache
  requests.
- Another, rework your application to have a parent component
  which will fetch data and pass it to the `HomeComponent` and
  `AboutComponent`.
- Also you can define some state service to store
  data. And inject it into your components, but it's the same to cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the problem with the first approach is that I have multiple calls to API's, not only one ( I said one in the question to simplify the problem) and I don't want to save every response. And I already have a parent component that is the entry point of the app, but is an empty page with only the navbar and the router outlet inside and I don't want to add business logic in that component.

Comment: @S-Wing You can rework  try  kind of MVP pattern and create  presenter  for both components which will  injected to both and  create parent  component  for both  to provide  presenter there. So it's kind of trick but it will  work :)

Comment: @Peter Mortesen Thank you for the answer; in any case, if I undestrand correctly, there isn't a way to load a component only once, I have to use a work-around like create a father component; is that correct?

Comment: @S-Wing don't think so. Also you can check out `RouteReuseStrategy` (https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy).

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I need; do you know where I can find some good documentation about RouteReuseStrategy? I'm asking because on the official ANgular site I find only the definition of the methods, and on other guides I have find a lot of confusion specially about the order in which the methods are called.

Comment: @S-Wing I looked at this article https://itnext.io/cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-3e4c8b174d5f hope it'll help you

Comment: Yes me too, but debuggin my code I noticed that the order and behaviour of methods is a little different; for example the method retrive is called before the method shouldAttach...ok nevermind I'll find some other tutorial or guide; thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so if you always need the results in the app, then I would say it is totally fine to do the solution I present, that we always no matter what, call all those http-requests (we found out in comments that there are multiple requests) and we would also use `shareReplay` like presented by Igor. Important to remember though here, that as long as the app is alive, the below presented variable `allPosts$` will never refetch the data, since we are using `shareReplay()`. If you need to refetch it at some time, I would suggest to expose a new observable, like `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`, which you can decide at some point to refetch all the data. But here let's assume that you don't need to refetch.

So in your service, when app is initialized, you can gather all those requests that you want executed with `forkJoin`, assign it to observable `allPosts$` and then in your components subscribe to `allPosts$`:

Sample:

```ts
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { shareReplay } from "rxjs/operators";
// ....

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class MyService {

  // gather all requests you want to be executed
  allPosts$ = forkJoin(this.getPost1(), this.getPost2(), this.getPost3()).pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPost1() {
    return this.http.get<Post>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
  }

  getPost2() {
    return this.http.get<Post>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2");
  }

  getPost3() {
    return this.http.get<Post>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3");
  }
}
```

Then in your component you would just subscribe to this observable like:

```ts
this.myService.allPosts$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

With this you get an array of all responses, in the order you have specified in `forkJoin`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer; this is a good workaround to avoid the re-call of webservices; however 
the solution I was looking for is RouteReuseStrategy

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject a service defined as a singleton. Cache the observable there and use `shareReplay`. Then you will only ever have one call to the API. In the example below you can inject `YourService` into your component(s).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {

  // Constructor omitted for brevity

  private $someResults: Observable<ISomeType>;
  getData() : Observable<ISomeType> {
   if(!this.$someResults) {
      this.$someResults = this.http.get<ISomeType>('end-point').pipe(shareReplay());
    }
    return this.$someResults;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the problem with this approach is that I have multiple calls to API's, not only one ( I said one in the question to simplify the problem) and I don't want to save every response.